Как в urlrewrite.php прописать подраздел для детальной страницы
Как  в urlrewrite.php прописать подраздел для детальной страницы. Как сделать url
категория/подкатегория/детальная страница. На данный момент у меня отображается /категория/детальная страница. Буду рад любой помощи
//urlrewrite.php
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/project_study/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).*#',
    'RULE' => 'ELEMENT_CODE=$1',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news.detail',
    'PATH' => '/project_study/detail.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),


Просто добавляем неиспользуемую часть:
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/project_study/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).*#',
    'RULE' => 'ELEMENT_CODE=$2',
    'ID' => 'myId',
    'PATH' => '/project_study/detail.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),

Либо, если делать дополнительную проверку в detail.php на соответствие подкатегории, то
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/project_study/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+).*#',
    'RULE' => 'SECTION_CODE=$1&ELEMENT_CODE=$2',
    'ID' => 'myId',
    'PATH' => '/project_study/detail.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),

ID следует сменить, чтобы битрикс не переписал правило.

Спасибо, но 404 ошибка выходит.

Значит, у вас генерится адрес, не подходящий под условие. Но это уже другой вопрос, не относящийся к исходному.

Виктор, Спасибо, за ответ и хорошую консультацию
